# Dry up rails namespaces in routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, namespaces

I have a couple of namespaces which look identical, the only difference between the two are the names. So I have

```
namespace :narrow do
  resources :posts
  resources :comments
  ...
  ...
end

namespace :wide do
  resources :posts
  resources :comments
  ...
  ...
end
```

What I would like to do is have the same resources defined in each namespace without needing to make changes in two places when resources are added/removed/changed.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isn't this just a ruby file?  couldn't you do:

```
[:narrow, :wide].each do |ns|
  namespace ns do
    resources :posts
    resources :comments
  end
end
```

Comment: Some days you get so drawn into the problem you fail to see the simple solutions in front of you :)